# Наиболее часто используемые правила русского языка при написании вопросов и ответов

Tags: поддержка, faq

#### Проблема

Многие технические специалисты в своё время не ставили перед собой задачу изучения правил правописания русского языка в широком смысле этого понятия.

#### Цель

Цель данной публикации — собрать некоторое количество наиболее распространённых ошибок правописания и на конкретных примерах объяснить участникам сообщества, каким образом использовать правила в тех или иных случаях.

#### Как добавить новое правило

Для того, чтобы добавить новое правило, пожалуйста:

- убедитесь, что его ещё нет в списке;
- убедитесь, что проблема действительно распространённая (всё-таки это сайт о программировании, а не о русском языке);
- добавьте новый ответ к этому вопросу в заданном формате (смотри далее).

Если вы наблюдаете проблему во многих сообщениях, и проблема ещё не описана в данной публикации, пожалуйста, добавьте ответ к этому вопросу, который содержит:

- Название правила правописания.
- Ссылка на правило русского языка на каком-либо авторитетном сайте.
- Пример ошибочного написания. Чем меньше текста, тем лучше, то есть, если достаточно одного предложения с ошибкой, значит, включаем только одно предложение.
- Пример того, какое написание было бы правильным.

### Правила

1. #### [Употребление прописной (большой, заглавной) буквы в начале предложения, в том числе и название вопроса.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5660/6)
2. #### [Отсутствие знаков препинания.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5661/6)
3. #### [Знаки препинания при вставных и вводных конструкциях.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5662/6)
4. #### [Знаки препинания в сложноподчинённом предложении.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5663/6)
5. #### [Знаки препинания в сложносочинённом предложении.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5664/6)
6. #### [Знаки препинания в бессоюзном сложном предложении.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5665/6)
7. #### [Союз чтобы (чтоб) пишется слитно.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5666/6)
8. #### [Частица или союз хотя бы пишется раздельно.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5667/6)
9. #### [Правописание устойчивого сочетания иметь в виду.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5668/6)
10. #### [Правописание местоимённых слов через дефис.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5669/6)
11. #### [Как пишется слово объект.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5670/6)
12. #### [Правописание -тся и -ться в глаголах.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5673/191482)
13. #### [Правописание НЕ и НИ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5687/199733)
14. #### [Правописание популярных слов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5816/199733)

Comment: Тут можно написать про "чтобы/что бы/что-бы" и "ться/тся"? Горит...))

Comment: баракин будет недоволен

Comment: Такими правилами ещё и никнейм придётся с большой буквы начать писать...

Comment: Осталось теперь дождаться когда кто-то придет и исправит "е"на "ё" в этом пресловутом "все–таки" :)

Comment: Грамматические нацисты одобряют.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Кто-то пришёл и исправил. К слову, в тексте поста были и другие ошибки, в том числе разбираемые ниже.

Comment: @Squidward всегда боюсь зафейлить такие моменты :D

Comment: А ещё в русском, в отличие от английского, два существительных подряд не подразумевают конверсию первого в прилагательное. Нужно либо менять падеж, либо писать через дефис, либо слитно. Пример: «прокси объект» → «прокси-объект», «хэш код» → «хэшкод», «диалог менеджер» → «менеджер диалогов». В ту же кассу «микро оптимизации» и «супер способности».

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите кто-нибудь про ["елемент"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)

Comment: @Dmitry это не столь критично и [Мы не будем тянуть в этот вопрос все правила русского языка.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39063680#39063680)  ....да и Цель данной публикации – собрать некоторое количество **наиболее распространенных** ошибок. уж этот пресловутый **е**лемент и прочие по мелочи можно уж подправить)

Comment: @Dmitry ... он же [eliment](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eliment), он же [ilement](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ilement)

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, кто-нибудь про правописание преставок) **при** и **пре**.

Comment: И ещё про различие приставок и предлогов.

Answer (score 8):

#### Правописание -тся и -ться в глаголах

[Основная идея](http://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=pravopisanie_tsia_v_glagolax)

> Буква  «ь» пишется в неопределённой форме глагола, которая отвечает
>   на вопросы   **что делать?**,     **что сделать?**
>
> Буква «ь» **не** пишется в формах глагола, которые отвечают на вопросы
>   **что делает?**, **что сделает?**
>
> Если в предложении нет подлежащего, и **вопрос к глаголу поставить
>
>   нельзя**, значит этот глагол стоит в форме 3-го лица ед. ч. и **пишется без ь**.

В программе начали (**что делать?**) появля**ться** первые ошибки.
В программе скоро (**что сделают?**) появя**тся** первые ошибки.
Саша (**что делает?**) учи**тся** программировать.

Answer (score 5):

#### Как пишется слово объект

[Основная идея](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=4405#pp4405)

> Разделительный ъ пишется после согласных перед буквами я, ю, ё, е, передающими сочетания [j] с гласными, в следующих случаях.
>
> - После приставок, оканчивающихся на согласный: в словах с русскими приставками, в словах с приставками иноязычного происхождения.
> - Так же пишутся слова иноязычного происхождения с начальными частями аб-, ад-, диз-, ин-, интер-, кон-, об-, суб-, которые в языке-источнике являются приставками, а в русском языке в качестве приставок обычно не выделяются.
> - В сложных словах: после начальных частей двух-, трёх-, четырёх-, в словах панъевропейский, фельдъегерь.
> - Буква ъ пишется также при передаче иноязычных собственных имён и производных от них слов (после букв, передающих парные твёрдые согласные)

**Ошибочное написание**: *Зачем нужен **обьект** SqlDataAdapter?*
**Правильное написание**: *Зачем нужен **объект** SqlDataAdapter?*

Answer (score 4):

#### Союз «чтобы» («чтоб») пишется слитно

[Основная идея](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=3917#pp3917)

> Союз «чтобы» пишется слитно (в одно слово). Его следует отличать от сочетания «что бы» (местоимение и частица), в котором частицу «бы» можно переставить в другое место предложения
>
> Сочетание «во что бы то ни стало» пишется в шесть слов.
>
> Союзы «тоже» и «также» пишутся слитно (в одно слово), причем оба союза синонимичны союзу «и». Союзы «тоже» и «также» следует отличать от сочетаний «то же» (местоимение с частицей) и «так же» (наречие с частицей). При сочетании «то же» часто стоит местоимение «самое». Кроме того, за сочетанием «то же» часто следует союзное слово «что».
>
> Союзы «причём» и «притом» имеют присоединительное значение (‘в добавление к этому’) и пишутся слитно (в одно слово). Союзы «причём» и «притом» следует отличать от сочетаний «при чём» и «при том» (местоимение с предлогом). Сочетание «при чём» употребляется в вопросительных предложениях. Сочетание «при том» обычно определяет следующее далее существительное.
>
> Сложные союзы «потому что», «так как», «так что», «для того чтобы», «тогда как» и др. пишутся раздельно (в два или три слова).

**Ошибочное написание**: *Надо, **что бы** эти значения передавались в массивы.*
**Правильное написание**: *Надо, **чтобы** эти значения передавались в массивы.*

**Ошибочное написание**: *Как реализовать запрос так, **что б** ответом был логин только что зарегистрированного пользователя.*
**Правильное написание**: *Как реализовать запрос так, **чтоб** ответом был логин только что зарегистрированного пользователя.*

---

**Когда надо писать «что-бы» через дефис или тире? — НИКОГДА!!!**

Слово «чтобы» **НИКОГДА** не пишется через дефис или тире!

**Ошибочное написание**: «что-бы», «что – бы», «что — бы».
**Правильное написание**: «чтобы».

Comment: может еще стоит добавить одно замечание (которое сейчас превалирует ужасно), как написано [здесь](http://chtoby-pravilno.ru/chtoby/): `Когда надо писать «что-бы» через дефис или тире?` — **НИКОГДА!!!** Слово «чтобы» **НИКОГДА** не пишется через дефис или тире!)) я просто не знаю как где вставить, чтоб вам тут не сломать идею)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, добавьте прямо в ответ дополнительным пунктом или отдельным замечанием. Идея одна – подсказать коллегам, в случае ошибки, как следует использовать правила.

Comment: добавил. не знаю правильно ли так было добавить

Answer (score 3):

#### Частица или союз «хотя бы» пишется раздельно

[Основная идея](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%8B)

> Усилительно–выделительная частица, близкая по значению к словам по крайней мере, по меньшей мере. Усилительная частица, близкая по значению к словам даже, пусть даже. Выделительная частица, близкая по значению к словам например, к примеру, вот. Выражение пожелания, надежды на что-либо.

[Еще немного правил.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_748)

**Ошибочное написание**: *Есть **хотябы** один пробел или перенос строки.*
**Правильное написание**: *Есть **хотя бы** один пробел или перенос строки.*

Comment: Никогда не видел слитного написания.

Comment: @Squidward примерно до середины 2016-го я никогда в жизни не видел как пишут "что-бы". Но потом, похоже, что-то где-то сломалось. Не удивлюсь, если тут тоже уже клинит. Хотя я тоже не видел ни разу))

Comment: @Squidward «есть ходьбы один пробел или перенос строки»

Answer (score 3):

#### Правописание местоименных слов через дефис

[Основная идея](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp135.php)

> Пишутся через дефис местоименные слова:
>
> - с начальной частью (приставкой) кое- (кой-);
> - с конечными частями (постфиксами) -либо, -нибудь, -то.

**Ошибочное написание**: *Может, **что нибудь** в коде неправильно?*
**Правильное написание**: *Может, **что-нибудь** в коде неправильно?*

**Ошибочное написание**: *Контроллер **почему то** ссылается на старый fxml-файл*.
**Правильное написание**: *Контроллер **почему-то** ссылается на старый fxml-файл.*

**Ошибочное написание**: *Могут использоваться и **какие либо** сложные серверные технологии.*
**Правильное написание**: *Могут использоваться и **какие-либо** сложные серверные технологии.*

Comment: Правило вводит в заблуждение. Важно понимать разницу между "почему-то комп сдох" и "почему то, что комп сдох, имеет значение". С кое-, -либо и -нибудь проще.

Answer (score 2):

#### Употребление прописной (большой, заглавной) буквы в начале предложения, в том числе и названии вопроса

[Основная идея](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81):

> Прописная буква употребляется в двух различных функциях. (1) Она служит для выделения начала определённых отрезков текста. (2) Прописная буква служит для выделения отдельных слов независимо от строения текста.

**Ошибочное написание**: ***ч**то за List? **и** в чём, собственно, проблема?*
**Правильное написание**: ***Ч**то за List? **И** в чём, собственно, проблема?*

**Ошибочное написание**: ***п**очему сайт появился в поисковике, но индекс равен 0?*
**Правильное написание**: ***П**очему сайт появился в поисковике, но индекс равен 0?*

Comment: Теперь буду ссылаться сюда при надоедании Баракину. 

Comment: @Squidward насколько я знаю, Александр прекрасно знает о правиле, мы с ним обсуждали этот вопрос. Он убежден, что с эстетической точки зрения, его подход более верен.

Comment: Жалко, что Баракина угораздило родиться в местности, где распространён язык с настолько однообразными буквами без хвостиков. В результате структурного недостатка алфавита возникает превратное мнение об эстетике в ущерб функциональности.

Comment: @Squidward: nemedlenno perehodim na ehstetichnuyu latinitsu?

Comment: @VladD любопытно, что в вашей версии транслита "эст" = "ehst". В моей, например, "est". Это не к тому, что какой-то из способов более верный, просто наблюдение.

Comment: @VladD Российские законы запрещают. В Татарстане пытались какое-то время назад. Суть в том, что за неровную строчку легче цепляться взглядом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: В той, к которой я привык, вообще `jest`, но она совсем уж экзотичная. А как в вашей отличаются «эст» и «ест»?

Comment: @Squidward: Вот прямо нам с вами запрещено писать транслитом? А насчёт «зацепиться взглядом» субъективно, у нас за какую-нибудь «ж» взгляд ещё как цепляется.

Comment: Если до предложения нет никакого текста (например это тайтл), большая буква "для выделения начала определённых отрезков текста." как бы избыточна.

Answer (score 2):

#### Отсутствие знаков препинания

[Основная идея](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=99#pp99):

> Пунктуация имеет чёткое назначение — способствовать расчленению письменного текста для облегчения его понимания. Расчленение может иметь разные основания: формально-грамматическое (учёт синтаксического строения предложения и его компонентов), смысловое (отражение содержательной значимости речи), интонационное (распределение пауз, логических и смысловых акцентов, передача эмоциональных нюансов речи).

**Ошибочное написание**: *Недавно познакомился с flexbox хотел сверстать макет используя flex'ы на второй картинке видно что именно я хочу сверстать я создал первый div которому дал свойство display:flex…*
**Правильное написание**: *Недавно познакомился с flexbox, хотел сверстать макет, используя flex'ы. На второй картинке видно, что именно я хочу сверстать. Я создал первый div, которому дал свойство display:flex…*

Answer (score 2):

#### Знаки препинания при вставных и вводных конструкциях

[Основная идея](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126#pp126)

> Вводные слова и сочетания слов выделяются или отделяются запятыми. К вводным словам относятся: *конечно, видно, кажется, например, к удивлению, во–первых, быть может, итак*.

[Ещё немного правил](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121).

**Ошибочное написание**: ***Может** есть способ…*
**Правильное написание**: ***Может,** есть способ…*

**Ошибочное написание**: ***Может быть** осветите более подробно задачу?*
**Правильное написание**: ***Может быть,** осветите более подробно задачу?*

**Ошибочное написание**: *Перерыл Инет, **но к сожалению** пока ничего не нашёл.*
**Правильное написание**: *Перерыл Инет, **но, к сожалению,** пока ничего не нашёл.*

**Ошибочное написание**: ***Я честно говоря** не понимаю.*
**Правильное написание**: ***Я, честно говоря,** не понимаю.*

**Ошибочное написание**: ***Возможно** дело не в CORS.*
**Правильное написание**: ***Возможно,** дело не в CORS.*

**Ошибочное написание**: ***Видимо** браузер кеширует ваши запросы.*
**Правильное написание**: ***Видимо,** браузер кеширует ваши запросы.*

**Ошибочное написание**: ***Думаю** в Интернете должна быть информация.*
**Правильное написание**: ***Думаю,** в Интернете должна быть информация.*

**Ошибочное написание**: ***Такое например** происходит с картами гугля или ютубом.*
**Правильное написание**: ***Такое, например,** происходит с картами гугля или ютубом.*

**Ошибочное написание**: ***Кажется** вы делаете что-то не так.*
**Правильное написание**: ***Кажется,** вы делаете что-то не так.*

**Ошибочное написание**: ***Команда по идеи** должна вызывать заполнение TotalInvestCollectionByu данными.*
**Правильное написание**: ***Команда, по идее,** должна вызывать заполнение TotalInvestCollectionByu данными.*

Answer (score 2):

#### Знаки препинания в сложноподчинённом предложении

[Основная идея](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)

> В придаточных частях сложноподчинённого предложения используются союзы и союзные слова будто, где, даром что, если (если... то), ибо, зачем, как будто, как только, как, какой, когда, который, кто, куда, лишь, лишь только, нежели, откуда, отчего, пока, поскольку, почему, словно, так как, так что, только что, точно, хотя, чей, чем, что, чтобы и др.
>
> Придаточная часть в сложноподчинённом предложении выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, если стоит внутри главной части; если же придаточная часть стоит перед главной частью или после неё, то отделяется от неё запятой.

[Ещё немного правил](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136)

**Ошибочное написание**: *Какую библиотеку установить чтобы исправить ошибку?*
**Правильное написание**: *Какую библиотеку установить, чтобы исправить ошибку?*

**Ошибочное написание**: *Не понимаю как и что передавать в функцию count.*
**Правильное написание**: *Не понимаю, как и что передавать в функцию count.*

**Ошибочное написание**: *Искал как реализовать P2P связь в C#.*
**Правильное написание**: *Искал, как реализовать P2P связь в C#.*

**Ошибочное написание**: *Есть сайт на котором все страницы подгружаются ajax'ом.*
**Правильное написание**: *Есть сайт, на котором все страницы подгружаются ajax'ом.*

**Ошибочное написание**: *Есть класс ViewModel который реализует INPC.*
**Правильное написание**: *Есть класс ViewModel, который реализует INPC.*

**Ошибочное написание**: *Если это так то вам нужна sp_executesql().*
**Правильное написание**: *Если это так, то вам нужна sp_executesql().*

**Ошибочное написание**: *От колонки идём вверх по дереву до тех пор пока не встретим элемент типа DataGrid.*
**Правильное написание**: *От колонки идём вверх по дереву до тех пор, пока не встретим элемент типа DataGrid.*

**Ошибочное написание**: *Этот способ не гарантирует того что вам прислали именно E-Mail адрес.*
**Правильное написание**: *Этот способ не гарантирует того, что вам прислали именно E-Mail адрес.*

Comment: Правило очень и очень упрощено, отсутствуют примеры разрыва основной части предложений, полностью проигнорирован случай нескольких придаточных, про страшные и ужасные правила с составными союзами и не говорю.

Comment: @Squidward Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что цитатой идет самая минимальная выжимка из правила, чтобы быстро вспомнить. По ссылке вы можете найти правило целиком, развернуто. Так в каждом ответе. Спешу заметить, что, обычно, по ссылке есть не только само правило но и набор примеров, на которых само правило рассматривается.

Answer (score 2):

### Правописание популярных слов

#### вообще

**Правильно**: вообще
**Неправильно**: **во**бще

#### в общем

**Правильно**: в общем
**Неправильно**: **во**бщем, **воо**бщем

#### отчасти

**Правильно**: отчасти
**Неправильно**: о**т ч**асти

Answer (score 1):

#### Знаки препинания в бессоюзном сложном предложении

[Основная идея](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135)

> Между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения при перечислении ставится запятая.

**Ошибочное написание**: *Есть сайт на нём есть личный кабинет.*
**Правильное написание**: *Есть сайт, на нём есть личный кабинет.*

Answer (score 0):

#### Знаки препинания в сложносочиненном предложении

[Основная идея](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=132#pp132)

> Запятыми разделяются предикативные части сложносочиненного предложения (простые предложения), между которыми стоят соединительные союзы, противительные союзы, разделительные союзы, присоединительные союзы, пояснительные союзы.
>
> Перед союзами «и», «да» (в значении «и»), «или», «либо» запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом.
>
> Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят: вопросительные предложения, побудительные предложения, восклицательные предложения, односоставные неопределенно-личные предложения, односоставные безличные предложения, имеющие синонимичные слова, односоставные номинативные (или назывные) предложения.

**Ошибочное написание**: *Код копирую в свой проект и там он не работает.*
**Правильное написание**: *Код копирую в свой проект, и там он не работает.*

Comment: Примеров маловато.

Answer (score -1):

#### Правописание устойчивого сочетания «иметь в виду»

[Основная идея](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83)

> Устойчивое сочетание (фразеологизм). Используется в качестве глагольной группы. Имеет смысл как:
>
> - учитывать, принимать в расчет;
> - подразумевать что–либо.

**Ошибочное написание**: *Что вы **имеете ввиду**?*
**Правильное написание**: *Что вы **имеете в виду**?*

**Ошибочное написание**: *Тут **имеется ввиду** таблица без кластеризованного индекса.*
**Правильное написание**: *Тут **имеется в виду** таблица без кластеризованного индекса.*

Comment: Правило вводит в заблуждение. Нельзя рассматривать его отдельно от слова "ввиду".

Answer (score -1):

#### Правописание НЕ и НИ

[Основная идея](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/138-def-19-24)

**НЕ пишется слитно**:

> 1. С полными и краткими прилагательными и с наречиями на -о (-е) , если сочетание их с не служит не для отрицания какого-либо понятия, а
>      для выражения нового, противоположного понятия.

**Ошибочное написание**: **Не с**табильные показатели.
**Правильное написание**: **Нес**табильные (т.е. изменчивые) показатели.

**Ошибочное написание**: **Не к**орректное отображение шрифта.
**Правильное написание**: **Нек**орректное (т.е. ошибочное) отображение шрифта.

**Ошибочное написание**: Шрифт отображается **не к**орректно.
**Правильное написание**: Шрифт отображается **нек**орректно.