# FAQ-вопрос с наиболее востребованными правилами правописания на Мете

Tags: обсуждение

#### Stack Overflow – сайт о программировании для программистов, зачем здесь обсуждать правила правописания?

Мы все разные, у нас разные жизненные ориентиры и системы ценностей: кто-то считает, что любое написание «сойдет», а для кого-то неправильное написание является неприемлемым. Главное, что нас объединяет – мы все увлечены программированием! Для того, чтобы избежать конфликтов интересов и поддерживать доброжелательную атмосферу знаний, на мой взгляд, нам необходимо стремиться взаимодействовать в рамках наиболее общеизвестных и общепринятых норм. Правила правописания в русском языке одни и те же для всех от Москвы до Нью-Йорка. Мне видится разумным стремиться максимально им следовать.

#### Почему не вынести все это дело, к примеру, на [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)?

Данная инициатива не предусматривает обсуждения правописания. Мы хотим лишь собрать в одном месте наиболее распространенные ошибки правописания, которые просты в своем освоении. Многих подобных ошибок можно избежать, если наглядно показать авторам вопросов, каким образом следует использовать правила правописания на конкретных примерах. С большой вероятностью наиболее эффективным будет их сбор «внутри сообщества» в одном FAQ-вопросе.

#### Набор правил – это пряник, а не кнут

Если вы пишите с ошибками – это не страшно! Мы все несовершенны! Нам всем есть куда стремиться, в чем совершенствоваться, что улучшать. Правила правописания собраны в одном [FAQ-вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5659/) для того, чтобы дать возможность любому желающему быстро и легко найти найти нужное.

Я не раз встречал весьма жесткие комментарии к вопросам авторов, когда те допускали ошибки в казалось бы тривиальных правилах правописания. Как мне кажется, мы можем избежать грубой критики, в то же время предоставив конструктивный полезный отзыв. Если вы видите ошибку правописания, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку в сообщение, а в описании правки укажите ссылки на правило правописания и почему в данном случае необходимо использовать именно его. Таким образом, на мой взгляд, проблема низкого внимания к правописанию будет решена более эффективно, чем она решается сейчас.

Спешу заметить, что публикацию не стоит рассматривать как нечто «запрещающее писать неверно». Наоборот, мы открыто говорим о проблеме и ищем эффективные пути ее решения. Грамотное написание – важно. Оно дает возможность сделать акцент на вложенный в сообщение смысл, а не на эмоции автора во время написания. Крайне сложно выучить правила в разрыве от конкретных примеров. Давайте вместе попробуем выучить русский язык прямо во время написания вопросов и ответов!

Ссылка на FAQ–вопрос для сбора основных правил: [Наиболее часто используемые правила русского языка при написании вопросов и ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5659/)

---

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что лично вы думаете о данной инициативе? Поможет ли она нашему сообществу и нашей базе знаний?

Comment: Историки потом не попросят отдельный фак-вопрос по часто встречающимся историческим ошибкам?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Это дело историков и организации их сообщества.

Comment: ...смысл узнавать мнения если решение уже давно принято?

Comment: Так как не у всех достаточно репы для просмотра оценок сообщений, то приведу их здесь. Вопрос — **+9/−4**. Ответы: **+10/−6**, **+8/−7**, **+3/−3**. Сообщество явно не в восторге.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper Да, определенная предварительная работа была проделана. Все же, использовать данный подход или нет, поддерживать FAQ–вопрос силами сообщества или нет — решаем мы все вместе.

Comment: Отвечать на вопросы участников или нет — решаем мы все вместе. Зачем эти очевидные комментарии? Проводить _подобный_ опрос сразу после принятия решения - нелепо. Большинству абсолютно все равно есть такая страница или нету - внимания обращать никто (кроме пары - тройки грамар-наци) на неё не будет. Но, полагаю, вы это знаете и без меня .

Comment: @Ev_Hyper мы стараемся сделать так, чтобы всем было комфортно. Если данной инициативой мы сможем сделать жизнь пары тройки людей лучше и приятнее – оно того стоило. Данная публикация – не опрос, это запрос на отзыв. То есть, было бы очень здорово увидеть, почему предложенная инициатива не будет работать, на что обратить внимание, как ее можно улучшить.

Comment: Хе, не опрос, как-же...Вот эту `Пожалуйста, подскажите, что лично вы думаете о данной инициативе?` часть не вы писали?. Почему инициатива работать не будет читайте первую часть ответа *Squidward*, если мои комментарий был недостаточно ясным. Но, если хотите, приведу немного цифр. За время существования FAQ весомый вклад внесли всего 3 участника из как минимум 11 поддержавших инициативу. Да и формулировка большинства правил оставляет желать много лучшего. Возможно стоило обратиться за помощью к специалистам? Например...на тот же [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Ev_Hyper Если вы видите проблему с формулировкой правил, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку!

Comment: ...если участник видит проблему это еще не означает, что он _хочет_ и/или _может_ её исправить.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper Если вы видите проблему и можете ее четко сформулировать, это будет уже огромный вклад в ее решение. Правильно поставленный вопрос – половина решения!

Answer (score 9):

Слишком идеализированно, потому работать не будет. Если кто-то пишет неграмотно, то это потому что ему покласть на правила, а не потому что где-то там не выложены правила русского языка, а в школе много лет не пытались научить грамоте.

В Сети правила русского — да и любого другого — языка находятся на расстоянии вытянутой руки. Доступны учебники на любой вкус и цвет, любого уровня сложности, детальные, вылизанные десятилетиями упорного труда их составителей. Кому не нравится текст — есть видео, есть аудио в конце концов. Для того, чтобы начать учиться, достаточно лишь желания. Достаточно хотеть писать грамотно и стремиться к этому.

Но всем пофиг.

Умение писать грамотно совершенно невостребованно в современном мире. Корректоры получают зарплату дворников. Книги — я уж молчу про газеты и интернетные издания — выпускаются с вопиющими ошибками, от которых волосы встают дыбом. Типографика в упадке.

На этом фоне выкладывать где-то на сайте написанную любителями жиденькую страничку с правилами русского языка и надеяться, что это повлияет на грамотность посетителей — по‑детски наивно.

Comment: "Но всем пофиг" — спорное утверждение. Ну хорошо, допустим это действительно "по-детски наивно", предлагайте другой вариант, "взрослый", а так, критиковать — дело несложное.

Comment: @edem Если бы я знал, как заставить людей уважать русский язык, то все вокруг его бы уважали. Вы наблюдаете такую картину? Нет. Значит, я такой магии не знаю.

Comment: Не соглашусь. Из моего личного опыта, грамотность вытекает из расставленных еще в школе приоритетов, где у меня математика была в приоритете, русский – нет, и, возможно, случайности (преподаватель не заинтересовал предметом). Сегодня, являясь более или менее квалифицированным специалистом я могу повысить приоритет русскому языку, а наличие задач по описанию процессов дают возможность не зубрить правила правописания, а запомнить их за счет использования на практике, что много эффективнее.

Comment: Все правила правописания, что я использую – следствие того, что кто–то из коллег поправил меня однажды, указав правильное написание и ссылку на описание самого правила. Ваше утверждение про оплату труда, на мой взгляд, не до конца верно, так как участники сообщества уже являются разработчиками, а правила правописания мы «подтягиваем», чтобы улучшить наши коммуникативные навыки, без которых, опять же, из моей практики, не перерасти из инженера в старшего инженера,
 так как любая руководящая позиция подразумевает обучение подопечных.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Сложные правила (как орфографические, так и пунктуационные) невозможно запомнить за счёт использования на практике: в них насчитывается под десять пунктов с исключениями и исключениями из исключений. Оплата труда корректоров — демонстрация невостребованности грамотности в современном мире, а не рассуждения о профессиях участников. Коммуникативные навыки, умение обучать и быть обучаемым имеют отношение к способности выбрать между слитным и раздельным написанием "не" примерно никакое. Из моего опыта.

Comment: @Squidward Чья–либо оплата ровным счетом ничего не значит: можно работать много и знать много, а получать мало, как и наоборот. Данная инициатива подразумевает сбор базовых правил в самом простом виде и ссылки на полные их описания. Я не планировал учить кого–либо русскому языку в общем смысле, но в то же время, было здорово дать возможность людям научить коллег/научиться писать чуть-чуть грамотнее.

Answer (score 6):

Если коротко, то я за. Чуть подробнее:

1. Кто ясно мыслит, тот ясно излагает.
2. Текст, в котором соблюдены правила правописания, приятнее читать, а это показывает уважение автора к своим читателям, да и к себе тоже, ибо речь, это как одежда: в грязной быть неприятно.
3. В ситуациях, когда автор знает *наверняка* как писать правильно, но, написав неправильно, не исправляет ошибки, "ибо лень", "да и так поймут", можно рассмотреть признаки неуважения к читателям, а подобного отношения желательно избегать.
4. Правильное написание требует определённой степени самодисциплины, как и верно обратное: стремление писать грамматически правильно — тренирует оную.
5. Стремление придерживаться стандартов, в данном случае правил русского языка, способствует всеобщему развитию: представьте, если бы не было RFC-стандартов и у каждого локального сообщества был бы свой "диалект" HTTP или TCP протокола, к чему бы это всё привело?
6. Можно предположить, что у автора привычку написания текстов в наплевательском стиле, также можно будет найти и в его коде: `a=b*3+i+qdf*f()-m();`, а вам потом это поддерживать. Поэтому лучше наставлять на светлую сторону заранее.
7. Почти любая программа, какая бы она не была, требует документации, от этого напрямую зависит её востребованность, а документацию пишут не на ЯП, а на человеческом языке.
8. Список очевидных ошибок с их пояснениями, который будет то и дело встречаться на данном сайте, может быть "лениво" заучен, когда перейдёшь на него разок другой из комментариев к вопросам, а это уже шаг вперёд.
9. База знаний, это как энциклопедия, и как все книги их, как правило, пишут на одном языке, а не на множестве "диалектов".
10. Человек ленив, а профессионал ценен, и чтобы стать профессионалом нужно весьма много преодолевать лень, поэтому не будем поощрять лень у участников при использовании такого важного инструмента, как изложение мыслей на письме на русском языке.

Comment: @Roman вносите улучшающие правки!

Comment: @Roman в описании правки не забудьте указать ссылку на FAQ с описанием правил :)

Comment: @Roman Общая идея данной инициативы не в том, чтобы подшучивать над коллегами, допустившими ошибку при написании, а в том, чтобы дать им ссылку в описании правки на крайне просто изложенное правило. Как мне кажется, если бы вы внесли улучшающую правку в ответ, сославшись на правила при необходимости, все бы были вам благодарны.

Comment: @Squidward Как в публикации, так и в комментарии выше, я хочу показать, что в том, что кто–то пишет с ошибками нет ничего страшного. Страшно то, что кто–то так и не научится писать грамотно после многих лет на сайте. Прийти и грубо высказать, что кто–то допустил столько–то и столько–то ошибок, посмеяться и уйти – не наш подход. Мы уважительно относимся ко всем нашим коллегам вне зависимости от их знания как программирования, так и правил правописания. Если вы видите ошибки правописания, пожалуйста, исправьте их и укажите автору в описании правки, какие правила и когда следует использовать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Или верните комментарии на место, или извольте объяснить, чем они оскорбительны (особенно учитывая, что комментарии edem про местоимение выжили). Двое человек написало про изобилие ошибок в тексте ответа, и не просто так: ответ изобилует оценками вроде "человек, допускающий ошибки, по-свински относится к собеседникам", поэтому указание на ошибки — это критически важная контр-аргументация и наглядная критика позиции, и никакое молчаливое исправление не может его заменить.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Что касается правил, то тратить час на поиск ссылок и разбор ошибок в каком-то левом сообщении на Мете, которое прочитает 10 человек — это откровенно пустая трата времени. На одни ссылки уйдёт несколько комментариев, а без разбора частного случая некоторые правила сложно понять, так что добавляйте ещё несколько комментариев сверху. Комментарий к правке вместит ещё меньше текста, чем комментарий к сообщению, кроме того о его существовании никто не узнает, потому что уведомлений нет.

Comment: @Squidward Если вы считаете, что комментарий к правке со ссылкой на правило не стоит вашего времени, пожалуйста, не добавляйте ссылку! Правка, как и любое другое действие на сайте – дело добровольное. Более того, в правилах сообщества ничего не говорится о грамотности. Все, что надо – это описывать проблему по программированию. С другой стороны, если ваша цель сделать свое окружение чуть-чуть лучше – передать свои знания, не только по программированию, коллегам, возможно набор правил в одном месте будет являться для вас крайне эффективным способом достижения поставленной цели.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Любой самопальный набор правил будет куцым и бесполезным. Правила, согласно которым решается 80% вопросов в русском языке, разбираются в начальных классах. Потом идут исключения и исключения из исключений. Выделять в этих редких правилах "самые важные" — бессмысленно, потому что правил сотни, и нарушаются они все. Если я захочу сослаться на правило, то пост на Мете СО — последнее место, где я буду его искать. Более того, орфографические правила "не/ни" и "н/нн" и синтаксические правила "как" и "тире/двоеточие" — это такой матан, что их "случайно" не запомнишь.

Comment: @Squidward Вы противоречите сами себе говоря, что 80% – это правила начальной школы, остальное – много много исключений, при этом, утверждая, что мы не сможем объять базовые правила. Более того, у нас нет задачи учить русскому языку в полной мере. Идея как раз в том, чтобы взять наиболее часто допускаемые ошибки из «80% базовых простых правил» и рассмотреть их. Если таким образом мы сможем повысить грамотность (уменьшить необходимость в улучшающих правках) – цель достигнута, мы – молодцы, так как участники сообщества смогут эффективнее расходовать время.

Comment: Не соглашусь с утверждением в третем пункте. Как мне кажется, [ошибки правописания в тексте — лишь отражение приоритетов автора](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39113444#39113444).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да, Вы, правы. Третий пункт, я написал, исходя из предположения, что автор текста знает как писать правильно, но, написав неправильно, не исправляет сообщение, ибо и так поймут, да и лень. Вот такой подход считаю наплевательским, а не любой текст написанный с ошибками, поэтому и сделал ударение на слове "Особенно", но этого было мало и мысль не поняли до конца.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, отредактировать - первое, что я попытался сделать, но у меня нет 2к репутации, а "_Правки-предложения для сообщений, не являющихся «общими», на Мете запрещены_", так что получилось только пошутить.

Answer (score 4):

В текущем виде затея мне **не** нравится. Это непрофильный для сообщества материал, следить за качеством которого тут мало у кого есть возможность и достаточная компетенция. На его сбор и поддержку требуется немало усилий. Когда эти же усилия можно употребить куда эффективнее, и на то, что в сообществе точно умеют.

## Предлагаю сменить формат на более сжатый.

Дело в том, что указания на эту шпаргалку не имеют отношения к сути сообщения изначально, и теряют всякую необходимость для вопроса, когда ошибки исправлены (автором ли сообщения или же мимо проходившим редактором). Короче говоря, **подобные указания должны жить недолго**.

Поскольку жить долго они не будут (из предположения, что задумке будут следовать), нет никакой необходимости делать "резервную копию" у нас на SE где бы там ни было. Бояться смерти ссылок нет смысла. Так что будет достаточно каталога ссылок на внешние источники с наиболее доходчивыми объяснениями. По одной ссылке на правило, без объяснений и примеров — это должно быть по ссылке. Опционально можно снабдить текстами для комментариев/правок, чтобы сэкономить редакторам время на ссылку, а заодно показать настрой, с которым эти ссылки предпочтительно прикладывать.

И на мой взгляд, сообщества [Русский Язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) и [Russian.SE](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) лучше подходят для составления такого FAQ. Не потому что это оффтопик для программистов, а потому что может быть полезно и для не-программистов тоже. Но это уже не столь критично.

---

У Russian.SE уже есть [список источников для изучения языка](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/833/6705). Это не совсем тот формат, о котором я говорю, но он может существенно облегчить сбор ссылок.

Comment: "Когда эти же усилия можно употребить куда эффективнее, и на то, что в сообществе точно умеют.", так как зарплату здесь не платят, то это всецело добровольное дело: куда, кому и на что тратить своё время.

Comment: @edem это ничего из вышесказанного не отменяет.

Comment: Отменять можно лишь то, что утверждено, а здесь ведётся обычный обмен мнениями.

Comment: @edem ок, то есть это дополнение. Выглядело как возражение.

Comment: Оно им и является. Посмотрите на текущий список правил русского языка; для его поддержки не требуются сотни человек, и сейчас там уже достаточно материала. Ну и если не интересоваться данной тематикой, то компетентным в ней точно не стать.

Comment: @edem я слежу за этим списком, потому и внес это предложение. Если в планах покрыть частые ошибки с той же гранулярностью, что сейчас, то список даже на четверть не готов. И нудные терминологические определения в большинстве из "правил" сложны для восприятия, и представляют ценность разве что для лингвистов, но не для рядовых читателей. А по всему интернету размещено огромное количество материала в т. ч. уровня младших классов, в который вложено много часов. И вот мы тут начинаем вкладывать свои часы примерно в то же. Тех, кому не всё равно, могло бы быть больше, если б их усилия ценились.

Comment: "А по всему интернету размещено огромное количество материала в т. ч. уровня младших классов, в который вложено много часов. И вот мы тут начинаем вкладывать свои часы примерно в то же", если бы программисты руководствовались этим подходом, то все мы продолжали бы писать лишь на Си и на парочке других языков. P.S. Не нравится, не делайте, не пойму в чём сложность, Вас же не заставляют этот список до идеала доводить.

Comment: @edem плохая аналогия подобна котёнку с дверцей. Если бы программисты руководствовались этим подходом, в мире было бы куда меньше велосипедостроения. И да, в своём ответе я именно и написал, что мне нынешний подход не нравится из-за своей неэффективности, и по этой причине я не возьмусь помогать. И предложил способ, которым можно здорово снизить "минимальное полезное усилие", чем привлечь к этому занятию больше людей, в зависимости от успешности возможно и меня.

Comment: "Если бы программисты руководствовались этим подходом, в мире было бы куда меньше велосипедостроения.", как программист Вы должны понимать, что так называемое Вами "велосипедостроение" является неотъемлемой частью обучения. А что же касается помощи, то сколько людей по Вашему мнению должны участвовать в данной затее, с учётом предложений, указанных в ответе?

Comment: "Короче говоря, подобные указания будут не должны жить долго." исправьте тут неточность.

Comment: @edem да, как-то дубово сформулировал, спасибо. Поправил.

Comment: @edem следуя вашей же аналогии, язык в такой ситуации будут изучать те, кто составляет этот список, а не те, кто будут его читать. Это проблема. А сколько человек? Чем больше, тем лучше, двое это как-то совсем мало. Сейчас существенный вклад в этот список поступил только от вас и Николаса. Остальное это е/ё, ёлочки и мелкое форматирование.

Comment: От меня там пока одно правило, а так да, основа за Николаем и Алексеем. И да, Вы правы в том, что написание правил способствует изучению языку, вот только с утверждением, что это никто читать не будет, согласиться не могу. Потому что если человек, делающий правки в сообщении, будет ссылаться на конкретные правила с примерами, то автор сообщения *при желании* сможет обратить на это внимание. P.S. На Мете в принципе не так много активных участников, так что 3 человека это весьма неплохо, а 5-6 идеально.

Comment: @D-side Подскажите, возможно стоит вовсе вынести сам FAQ в текущем формате на сайт Русский язык?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не знаю. Стоит поболтать об этом у них на Мете. Это может стать "вики-проектом сообщества", как у нас списки литературы, и там есть специалисты в этой области. Вопрос только в том, считают ли они это нужным и/или полезным и будут ли поддерживать/дополнять.

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, куда важнее искоренить использование жаргона в вопросах и
ответах на сайте. Фактически он употребляется из-за недостаточного знания
русского языка, т.к. эти «слова» в основном заимствованы из английского (на
самом деле это просто английские слова записанные кириллицей, что выглядит
просто отвратительно). Порой начнёшь читать какой-нибудь ответ, а там сплошные
«партиции», «дефиниции», «имплементации», «сайд-бары», «бафферы» и «фанкции».*
Ну, народ, ну не стыдно, а?

Вообще, у нас уже есть [специальная тема на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1267/183314), где можно поискать
русскую замену подобным буквосочетаниям. Но судя по всему, это не особо
помогает :(. Неужели этот свод правил на мете решит проблему неграмотного
использования языка?

К большому сожалению, проблема слишком глобальна. Справится ли с ней
сообщество Stack Overflow на русском? (Хотя бы в пределах своего сайта.)

<sub>* раздел, определение, реализация, боковая панель, буфер, функция</sub>

Comment: По моему субъективному впечатлению, подобные слова-паразиты сыпятся из уст (и из-под клавиатуры) тех, кто и с английским языком не особо знаком.

Comment: Да, примеры страшные. Правда, на практике я встречал только "партиции" и "сайдбары". Последнее, кстати, считаю вполне оправданным, т. к. значительно короче, чем "боковая панель" (и на письме, и в речи: "сайдбар" имеет вдвое меньше слогов чем одно слово "боковая"), и с другими словами языка не конфликтует. UPD: хотя не, вру, "имплементации" тоже встречал.

Comment: Профессиональный сленг в любой профессии обрастает кальками с языка, который в этой профессии доминирует. Сейчас это почти везде — английский. Бороться с явлением бесполезно. Более того, где в "декларации" и "дефиниции" запрятались "объявление" и "определение" — это ещё надо мозг напрячь и вспомнить. И даже если вспомню, то разъяснить разницу между "string" и "line", которые по-русски едины — всё равно сложно. Если раньше были какие-то попытки придумать профессиональную терминологию, то сейчас такой разброд и шатание, что проще пойти по короткому пути.

Comment: Тем не менее, StackOverflow — не форум, а база знаний, нечто сродни книгам. При составлении сообщений следует избегать разговорной лексики, сленга и жаргона в любом их проявлении.

Comment: @Squidward Как мне кажется, знакомить людей с культурой и языком можно и нужно. Весь вопрос в подходах. Если насильственно навязывать что–либо, то, да, тольку будет мало. Если же мы будем показывать как следует грамотно и лаконично излагать мысли на собственном примере, уверен, коллеги последуют нашему примеру.

Answer (score 0):

Против.

FAQ по правописанию никак не связано с тематикой сайта. Не думаю, что люди задающие здесь вопросы ожидают увидеть в комментариях отсылки к учебникам правописания, словарям или списку самых распространенных ошибок в орфографии. Если бы участник хотел уточнить, например, правила пунктуации то, очевидно, что есть намного более подходящее место чем сообщество программистов.

На мой взгляд, комментарии подобного рода - очевидный оффтоп (вредоносный шум), который только мешает разобраться в проблеме поставленной в том или ином вопрос. То есть как раз то, чего SO всегда старался избегать.

Как правильно отмечено в вопросе, каждый пишет так как может. Причины могут быть самые разные - например, русский язык может быть не родным.

Поэтому давайте не будет тыкать друг друга в очевидные (на ваш взгляд) ошибки - это не дружелюбно. А их наличие вовсе не означают наплевательское отношение к окружающим - так или иначе их совершает каждый.

Comment: Ссылку предлагается упоминать в описании правки, а не в комментарии к сообщению. Никакого лишнего шума, если не считать поднятие сообщения из-за правки как таковой не возникнет.

Comment: @alexolut, главное, чтобы не получилось вот так -https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVsJh.png

Comment: @alexolut а я бы, как раз, указывал бы в комментарии, ибо там читают, а в описании к правке кто будет читать? всё равно, что записку оставлять не на столе, а приклеенную скотчем под столом.

Comment: `Причины могут быть самые разные - например, русский язык может быть не родным.` - так разве это не прекрасно, когда помимо обучения программированию ты можешь параллельно подтянуть язык, на котором будешь общаться с коллегами, с потенциальными клиентами/заказчиками, возможно делать презентации для широкой публики? Я, написав вопрос на английском был бы только рад, если бы мне подсказали о неточностях в написании и помогли освоить тонкости и залатать шероховатости языка, который мне необходим для коммуникации.

Comment: А вот обижаться и относиться враждебно к этому могут лишь те, кто приходит за решением для бездумной копипасты в проект для залатывания бездумных дырок и считает, что все обязаны сосредоточиться на решении их и только их проблемы. Те, кто сам наплевал на нормы общества, их устои и правила. Те, в принципе, будут обижаться на любые отсылы, потому что сами всех виртуально отсылают.  Премьер-министр Австралии Джон Говард говорил "Иммигранты, а не австралийцы, должны приспособиться.". Аналогично и тут, почему нормы русского сообщества должны подстраиваться под кого-то, а не наоборот?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я привел самый очевидный пример, но есть и множество других. Например - проблемы со слухом. Вы видели как вначале люди высмеивают пользователя за его орфографию, а потом в дальнейшем они приносили извинения (в лучшем случае)? Уверен, что не раз. Или, другой пример, украинский очень похож на русский, но есть множество мест сложных для перевода. Английский это немного другой случай

Comment: @АлексейШиманский отчего-же? Вы задаете вопрос не для того, чтобы узнать какие ошибки вы допускаете, а затем, что вам нужна помощь в конкретном вопрос. Заметили ошибку в вопросе/ответе - поправили и все довольны, автор заметит что его сообщение отредактировано и если захочет ознакомится детальнее

Comment: @FoggyFinder причем тут проблемы со слухом? Совсем плохо с письмом обстоит совсем у глухих людей. И то, они хоть и сложно, но обучаемы. Слабослышащие и позднослышащие довольно неплохо справляются. Такое ощущение, что вы людей с проблемами со слухом приравняли к умственно-отсталым. `. Или, другой пример, украинский очень похож на русский, но есть множество мест сложных для перевода.` - и в чем проблема? Почему с интересом не узнать в чем заключается проблема, изучить её и стать чуть опытнее в доведении мысли? Ну если хочется остаться необразованным - то, ок. Тогда смысл общаться на этом языке?

Comment: @FoggyFinder `автор заметит что его сообщение отредактировано и если захочет ознакомится детальнее` - автор заметит, что сообщение поправили и еще больше расслабится, так как за него сделают всю работу. Ему остаётся лишь вывалить поток сознания и идти гулять. Остальное за него сделают: и отредактируют, и отформатируют код, и ответы напишут и спать уложат.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  `причем тут проблемы со слухом? Совсем плохо с письмом обстоит совсем у глухих людей. И то, они хоть и сложно, но обучаемы. Слабослышащие и позднослышащие довольно неплохо справляются.`  я привожу различные примеры когда в сообщениях могут быть ошибки орфографии в качестве подтверждения того, что это не является неуважением к остальным участникам.  `Такое ощущение, что вы людей с проблемами со слухом приравняли к умственно-отсталым` ваше ощущение ошибочно. Не уверен, что правильно понял или вы приравняли всех, кто допускает орфографические ошибки к умственно-отсталым?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `автор заметит, что сообщение поправили и еще больше расслабится, так как за него сделают всю работу.` просто не нужно додумывать за автора что он сделает или не сделает. Кто-то расслабиться, а кто-то заинтересуется и попробует узнать больше о том, где ошибся.

Comment: @FoggyFinder `я привожу различные примеры когда в сообщениях могут быть ошибки орфографии в качестве подтверждения того, что это не является неуважением к остальным участникам` - ну хорошо. Отсюда видим, что если человек изначально не враждебно настроен, то никаких проблем с тем, чтобы поднять свои навыки в каком-либо аспекте - у него не вызовет никакой боли. Поэтому и проблема с обидами на отсыл к прочтению FAQ  надуманная

Comment: @АлексейШиманский *так разве это не прекрасно, когда помимо обучения программированию ты можешь параллельно подтянуть язык, на котором будешь общаться с коллегами* — Это для вас или для меня прекрасно. А давать советы по правописанию без разбора кому попало считается неуместным и даже неприличным (не то чтобы это меня останавливало, но я — это я). Первое правило этикета — не учить других этикету.

Comment: `Поэтому и проблема с обидами на отсыл к прочтению FAQ надуманная` о том и речь, что не надуманная. Даже в самом вопросе отмечено, что `Я не раз встречал весьма жесткие комментарии к вопросам авторов, когда те допускали ошибки в казалось бы тривиальных правилах правописания.`

Comment: @FoggyFinder так вы почитайте о сути. Она и призвана убрать эти самые жесткие или язвительные комментарии. Чтобы не было повода это сделать, а можно было мягко и корректно сообщить о неточностях, с которыми неплохо было бы ознакомиться. И направить в нужное русло. Никто не собирается писать в стиле "Ты чё, не умеешь писать чтоль по-русски? В школе не учили? Вот специально для таких неучей создали топик, иди развивайся!". Вы ведь не так себе, надеюсь, представляете эту инициативу? А то что-то мне подсказывает...))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `так вы почитайте о сути. Она и призвана убрать эти самые жесткие или язвительные комментарии` я думаю, что подобным комментариям не место на SO. `Вы ведь не так себе, надеюсь, представляете эту инициативу?`. Конечно, нет. Но в данном случае для меня абсолютно не важно мягко или цинично участнику указывают на ошибки в правописании. `А то что-то мне подсказывает...))` опять вы меня неправильно понимаете :(

Comment: @FoggyFinder `Но в данном случае для меня абсолютно не важно мягко или цинично участнику указывают на ошибки в правописании.` - а еще ответы на вопросы не писать, чтобы не указывать участнику на ошибки, а то мало ли что с человеком приключится)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ага, и правок никаких в сообщения не вносить, дабы не намекать на наличие "неточностей" в оных, а то обидятся.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Еще раз спешу подчеркнуть, что ссылку предлагалась давать в описании к правке, после ее внесения, вместо того, как это делается сейчас – без правки в комментарии. То есть цель инициативы: (1) снижение агрессии, с одной стороны; (2) предоставить возможность донести до коллег правила правописания в дружелюбной эффективной манере тем, кто этого хочет с другой.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky (1) подобные действия никак не снизят агрессию, те кто писал комментарии подобного рода продолжат их писать.  (2) попытка вместить в SO то, для чего он не предназначен - плохая идея.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Мы не расширяем тематику сайта, на SO ровным счетом ничего не добавляется. С другой стороны, мы предоставляем желающим научить коллег русскому языку простой и эффективный способ это сделать, так как комментарии–ссылки на правила русского языка должны удаляться. В моем понимании, данная инициатива – это качественное улучшение текущей системы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я пытаюсь донести мысль, что правила русского языка не относятся к тематике SO на русском. Есть же специализированный сайт. Например, сейчас добавили FAQ с правописанием, затем, как уже проводили аналогию - FAQ с исторической справкой?

Comment: @FoggyFinder соглашусь, что SO о программировании. Все же, мы вносим улучающие правки, которые улучшают не код, а грамотность сообщения. Опять же, я вижу комментарии отсылающие авторов к правилам того же ться/тся. Сейчас мы можем сделать систему лучше. Добавление самых базовых правил в один вопрос на Мете и ссылка на него в описании правок никак не расширит и не сузит тематику сайта, но даст «легальную» возможность, при желании, улучшить знания наших коллег.

Answer (score -1):

А я как раз за кнут. Считаю что нужно закрывать безграмотные вопросы, а ответы удалять. Для этого потребуется добавить соответствующие пункты в диалоге закрытия.

Comment: Не для всех русский язык родной, поэтому узлы лучше развязывать, чем рубить.

Comment: @edem, вообще-то у нас тут общество **на русском языке**. Но с подобной радикальностью я, конечно, не согласен, хотя очень хочется.

Comment: Мы и пряником можем побить. )